# How can I apply_filters from inside a function?

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I have this function in theme-child/functions.php that shows a different total value in cart depending on the category of the chosen product:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'change_calculated_total', 10, 2 );

function change_calculated_total( $total, $cart ) {
    
    $symbol = 'U$';    
    $value = 1;

    $cat_ids = array();
    foreach ( wc()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $cat_ids = array_merge(
            $cat_ids, $cart_item['data']->get_category_ids()
        );
    }
    if (in_array(70, $cat_ids)) {
        $symbol = 'AR$';
        $value = $value * 100;
    }

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency', $symbol ); // this line should call the function that changes the currency symbol.

    return $value;
}
```

And this one to change the currency symbol:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currency_symbol', function( $symbol ) {
    return $symbol;
}
```

So in the first one, depending on the category id, I need to change the total value (working) and the currency symbol but I don't know how to call it.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: That's to how filters work, keep in mind that timing and order matter too, but you would need to ask about that in a WooCommerce community, 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here

Comment: Oh thanks. I thought it was kinda the same because you would think of products categories as posts categories and filters are WordPress' and not Woocommerce. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: `add_filter` expects a callable value as the second parameter, e.g. a function, a reference to a class and method, etc, it can't directly provide a replacement value. You can ask about filters here, but only in the generic sense. You can't ask how a specific WooCommerce filter works.